# TinyMCE on textarea: text between tags is not shown

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, textarea

I've a simple TinyMCE and I want to fill out the `textarea`, but the text is not shown and the `textarea` is still empty. Can someone please tell me whats wrong? If it works, I will put the text with a PHP `echo` on this place.

Here is my TinyMCE on my `textarea`.

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    language: 'de',
    object_resizing: false,
    style_formats: [
    {title: 'Headline', block: 'h4', styles: {color: 'black'}},
    {title: 'Text', block: 'p', styles: {color: 'black'}},
    ],

    toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image | bullist | headline |  |  |  | ",
    menu: "|",
    height: "500px",
    resize: false,
    });
</script>

<textarea id="desc" name="de_desc">THIS IS MY TEXT</textarea>
```

Comment: also wird dir nur der testtesxt nicht angezeigt oder auch nicht wenn du etwas rein schreibst ?

Comment: Nichts wird angezeigt. Weder wenn ich normalen Text reinschreibe und auch nichts wenn ich mit php echo was reinschreibe.

Comment: hast du mal versucht deine options weg zu lassen und sie nach und nach rein zu schreiben... also erst selector dann language etc. und muss language nicht de-DE sein? weiß es grade nicht genau

Comment: @Dwza: "de" ist korrekt, bzw. geht auch "de_AT"

Comment: dachte mir schon das es ander sprache liegt :) aber gut, thariama hat die lösung :) hier die sprachen [tinyMCE Languagepacks](http://www.tinymce.com/i18n/)

Comment: tinymce fiddle ist jedenfalls Gold wert um Fehler in der Konfiguration zu finden (ein Blick in die JS-Console lohnt auch meist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

The problem was, that the name of my textarea:

```
name="de_desc"
```

had an underscore! If I only named it in "desc" it worked! Don't know why, but now it works as I expected.
Thanks for your help gyus!

Answer (score 1):

English:

The problem is you are trying to load a language that seems not to be installed.

```
Error: Failed to load: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/tinymce/4.0.12/langs/de.js
```

Here is a working [tinymce fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/aJdaab) with your tinymce config except the language param.
Solution will be to make sure the language "de" is available/installed in your tinymce.

---

Deutsch:

Das Problem hier ist, dass die deutsche Sprache nicht installiert zu sein scheint:

```
Error: Failed to load: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/tinymce/4.0.12/langs/de.js
```

Einen funktioniernden [tinymce fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/aJdaab) habe ich gebaut, der ohne den language-Parameter wunderbar läuft. Lösung wäre dann die Sprache "de" nachzuinstallieren.